# Behaviour of preincrement operator

Tags: c++, runtime

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  vector<int> v = { 1 };
  auto it = v.begin();
  cout << ++(*it) << " " << v[0] << " " << endl;
  cout << v[0] << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When compiled and run, this code yields the following console output:

```
2 1 
2
```

Given that `++(*it)` increments the first vector value, I would instead expect the following output:

```
2 2 
2
```

Why isn't the increment reflected in the first `cout` statement for `v[0]`?

Comment: There isn't a defined sequence point within the expression at which the ++ operator should be applied.

Comment: I cant figure out why someone has downvoted my question?

Answer (score 2):

The reason being,:

```
cout<<++(*it);
```

is printing the next value `2` but the original value of v increases only after the the line:

```
cout<<++(*it)<<" "<<v[0]<<" "; // v[0] is still `1`
```

Now the value `v[0]` is incremented and result is `2`

```
cout<< v[0]<<" ";
```

You can increment before the `cout`

```
++(*it);
cout<<*it<<" "<<v[0]<<" ";
```

Now the output will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`++(*it)` will increment and return the element `it` refers to, not the iterator itself, so `v[0]` is `2` after evaluating that expression.

So why doesn't it print `222`?
Because the chain of `operator<<`s is actually nested function call, somewhat like this:

`operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, ++(*it)), " "), v[0]), " ");`

and the bit of interest:

`operator<<(operator<<(std::cout, ++(*it)), " "), v[0])`

This is a function call with two arguments, `operator<<(std::cout, ++(*it))` and `v[0]`.
The order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified, one platform or compiler may do it differently than another (left to right and right to left are common, as far as I know).

If the second argument is evaluated first, `v[0]` is retrieved while still holding `1`, and we print `212`.

If the first argument is evaluated first, `++(*it)` happens first, and `v[0]` is retrieved after, so we print `222`.

Unfortunately, the C++ standard only guarantees that the evaluation of all arguments is sequenced before the  function body, but not with respect to each other.

Using both `v[0]` and `++v[0]` in unsequenced expressions may invoke *undefined behavior* - which could do exactly what you want, or launch the missiles.

Comment: You are right about the fact that its actually an overloaded function call and there are no guarantees about the evaluation of arguments.But this gives me another doubt-What does the concept of left associativity of << operator mean then?(overloaded<< is also left associative).Shouldnt left associativity ensure that first arguement is  always evaluated first?

Comment: @TarunBhargava left-associative only means `a << b << c` groups like `((a << b) << c)`, and a right-associative operator like `=` groups like `(a = (b = (c = 4)))`